# HPA with Sumologic in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hpa, sumologic

I have started receiving Spikes intermittently. I am using Sumologic for logs. I am thinking of using HPA. My K8S is in house setup. Does Sumologic support HPA? Service is implemented using ClusterIP.  Duw to spike service returns 503.
I feel HPA should be implemented. Not sure Sumologic works with HPA?

Comment: I think the question deserves a bit more explanation and details on what have you tried/searched so far